# SumCalc attribute not working when trying to summarize usr Field from PMTask to PMProject

Tags: acumatica

First, created a custom field in the PM.PMTask DAC called usrNumberofPanel

Second, created a custom field in the PM.PMProject DAC usrTotalPanels.

Want each of the lines from task to update the total number of panels on the project, so modified the attribute for PM.PMTask.userNumberofPanel and added a PXFormula as shown below to add the SumCalc.

```
[PXDBDecimal]
[PXUIField(DisplayName="Number of Panels")]
[PXFormula(null, typeof(SumCalc<PX.Objects.CT.ContractExt.usrTotalPanels>))]
```

Made sure the attributes for the Total Panel and set as follows to make sure no one types into the field.

```
[PXDBDecimal]
[PXUIField(DisplayName="Total Panels", Enabled = false)]
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a known issue that SumCalc doesn't work properly across DACs that are linked with PXParent relationships.

I can only recommend to use a `RowSelected` or `FieldSelecting` graph event handlers to compute the sum instead of a solution involving DAC attributes. You can add a comment explaining the limitation of DAC attributes in the event handler if you are seeking Acumatica ISV Certification for your solution.

Comment: Thank you.  I had to actually add a PXParent relationship and that solved the issue.  Here is what I added:  `[PXParent ( typeof(Select<CT.Contract,Where<PX.Objects.CT.Contract.contractID, 
          Equal<Current<PX.Objects.PM.PMTask.projectID>>>>))]`